# i am using http post method to update the database in android application but i am getting the following error

Tags: android, http-post

11-10 13:32:47.398: E/AndroidRuntime(2155): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 13:32:47.398: E/AndroidRuntime(2155): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-10 13:32:47.398: E/AndroidRuntime(2155):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
11-10 13:32:47.398: E/AndroidRuntime(2155):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
11-10 13:32:47.398: E/AndroidRuntime(2155):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
11-10 13:32:47.398: E/AndroidRuntime(2155):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)

error at public class UpdatingDatabase extends AsyncTask

```
package com.nikhil.svs;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Register extends MainActivity {

    EditText reg,pwd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

         reg=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editusername);
         pwd=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
         Button register=(Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new UpdatingDatabase().execute();
                }

                public class UpdatingDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
                {
                 protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) { //add this line
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://nikhilvaddepati.tk.hostinghood.com/test.php");
                            String a=reg.getText().toString();
                            String b=pwd.getText().toString();

                            try {
                                // Add your data
                                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regno", ""+a));
                                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd",""+b));                  
                                httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                            }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            }

                        }

                public void execute() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
                      }// and this brackets
                        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code please, because there are many reasons to trigger this. you need to know that in android versions of >= 4 you need to use threads to get a network and make sure that you don't do any network access on UI Thread, instead do it in Async Task

Comment: please look at the code

Comment: what is `public void execute() { }//' for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have stated in the comment, you need to use threads to get a network and make sure that you don't do any network access on UI Thread, instead do it in Async Task

you have to move the code within the onClick button to AsynTask...

it should look like the following.

Edited!

```
public void onClick(View v) {
new UpdatingDatabase().execute();
}

public class UpdatingDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
 protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) { //add this line
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://nikhilvaddepati.tk.hostinghood.com/test.php");
            String a=reg.getText().toString();
            String b=pwd.getText().toString();

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regno", ""+a));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd",""+b));                  
                httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }

        }
      }// and this brackets
}
```

now this is how it suppose to be, it will fix your error. Please inform me if it worked

Edit:

```
final EditText reg, pwd;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    reg=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editusername);


    pwd=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);

    ...// complete with the code
```

Edit 2:

```
package com.nikhil.svs;

 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;

 public class Register extends MainActivity {

EditText reg,pwd;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

     reg=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editusername);
     pwd=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpassword);
     Button register=(Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new UpdatingDatabase().execute();
            }
          });
         }

            public class UpdatingDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
            {
             protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) { //add this line
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://nikhilvaddepati.tk.hostinghood.com/test.php");
                        String a=reg.getText().toString();
                        String b=pwd.getText().toString();

                        try {
                            // Add your data
                            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regno", ""+a));
                            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd",""+b));                  
                            httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                            // Execute HTTP Post Request
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }

                    }

                  }
                 }
```

Comment: same errors?! if other errors please edit and add the new errors

Comment: make the editboxes global, declare both editboxes before onCreate however, refer to them in the onCreate.

Comment: i am getting error as source not found defaultrequestdirector.class

Comment: My bad i forgot the most important part in the `AsyncTask` which is the `doInBackground` -_- please re-check the first code block and under the `AsyncTask` there is the `doInBackground` line need to be added with the brackets. inform me the result

Comment: hey....with out using doInBackground..i almost cleared my errors...but getting error at class name in line public class UpdatingDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>

Comment: ya because there must be a `doInBackground` methog in the `AsyncTask` dont forget the ending bracket

Comment: can u just show me the code how and where to insert it....i will edit and re post the total code please help me with it

Comment: I rewrote the `asynctask` just copy paste it, check the second line after the `public class UpdatingDatabase extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>` you will find `doInBackground`.

Comment: please look at the code now....if not possible can u just give me your mail id so that i will mail my project to you so that you u could help me :)

Comment: You had a lot of brackets problem all fixed copy paste EDIT 2 and run it and if it didnt work sent it to my mail